# Multiple Object use across class c#

Tags: c#

I have three classes that hold data from an input form and then each submit an insert query to the database.

There must be a better way of doing this with using the existing objects and a singular stored procedure, but I can't get the existing objects to work in another class. I apologise for the simplicity of the question as I imagine this to be a very straightforward fix to tidy up my code.

With the code below what I am trying to achieve is to reuse the existing instances of EndUser, Bank and Company in the StoredProc class so I don't have to use SQL queries in each class method and only one save method from the StoredProc class.

**Edit**
To clarify the database stuff ie the SQL string isn't the issue, what I am trying to ask is can I use instances of existing objects (three of them) in the storedproc class so I can use one (already written) stored procedure?

Apologies the code is a bit long but I have thinned it down as much as possible whilst still making sense (as well as running):

**Form backend**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EndUser newUser = new EndUser(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
        Company newcmpny = new Company(textBox4.Text, textBox3.Text);
        Bank newbank = new Bank(textBox6.Text, textBox5.Text);
        newUser.Save();
        newcmpny.Save();
        newbank.Save();
    }
}
```

**DataHold classes (all in one file)**

```
    class EndUser
{
    public EndUser(string first, string last) {
        firstName = first;
        lastName = last;
    }
    public int iD { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }

    public void Save()
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDatabase"].ConnectionString))
        {
            string sqlQuery = (@"INSERT INTO [EndUser] (FirstName, LastName)
                            VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName)");
            connection.Open();

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("FirstName", firstName).ToString();
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("LastName", lastName).ToString();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}

class Company
{
    public Company(string cmpny, string tele)
    {
        company = cmpny;
        telephone = tele;
    }

    public string company { get; set; } // textbox4
    public string telephone { get; set; } // textbox3

    public void Save()
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDatabase"].ConnectionString))
        {
            string sqlQuery = (@"INSERT INTO [Company] (CName, Telephone)
                            VALUES (@CName, @Telephone)");
            connection.Open();

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("CName", company).ToString();
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Telephone", telephone).ToString();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}

class Bank
{
    public Bank(string bn, string scode)
    {
        name = bn;
        sortcode = scode;
    }
    public string name { get; set; } // textbox6
    public string sortcode { get; set; } // textbox5
    public void Save()
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDatabase"].ConnectionString))
        {
            string sqlQuery = (@"INSERT INTO [Bank] (BankName, SortCode)
                            VALUES (@BankName, @SortCode)");
            connection.Open();

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("BankName", name).ToString();
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("SortCode", sortcode).ToString();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}

class StoredProc
{
    public void ToTheDB()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDatabase"].ConnectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Procedure",con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FirstName", newUser.firstName);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why don't u create stored procedures in your database program?

Comment: Then I would have three stored procedures (if I'm understanding you correctly) and would like to be able to use just one from the storedproc class using the variable data from existing instances of the other classes. Unless this isn't possible/isn't worth it?

Comment: You can use the entity framework. I think most of your code will be reduced.

Comment: As Mahesh said: If you do not want to write all the boilerplate code for database CRUD, use the EntityFramework.

Comment: I have added an edit to the question, think I have caused some mis-communication from my end, apologies, the issue here isn't with SQL, it's with using existing instances of objects in another class.

Comment: What do you think is the purpose of `ToString()` in lines like `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("BankName", name).ToString();`?

Comment: There isn't, it should always be a string, but that was just copy and pasted.

Comment: @PurpleSmurph the `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("BankName", name).ToString();` doesn't do anything, only the `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("BankName", name);` is actually needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all - IMO it's a badly written code.

My advises:

- Do not mix the models and SQL queries or any database logic.
- Do not use plain SQL in C# code, but rather use Entity Framework or Stored Procedures.
- Do not save multiple entities which share the same business logic without wrapping them with single transaction.

You have asked: "can I use instances of existing objects (three of them) in the storedproc class so I can use one (already written) stored procedure"

The answer is - you can hardly use the existing code in that way. You don't have the stored procedure as far as I can see. You have just strings with SQL queries.

Anyway, you can try to use your classes as models in storedproc class and create new stored procedure which uses them.

It should look something like this:

```
class StoredProc
{
    public void ToTheDB(EndUser endUser, Company company, Bank bank)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDatabase"].ConnectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Procedure",con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                //Here you can use data from your "model" classes and add them as parameters for your stored procedure.
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = endUser.firstName;
                //the rest of the parameters from EndUser, Company and Bank classes

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Once again, you should separate your logic and models.

It's an example model:

```
public class Bank
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string sortCode { get; set; }
}
```

Ant this is method of Data Access Layer or Repository:

```
void AddBank(Bank bank)
{
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDatabase"].ConnectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            //Procedure for inserting
            using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Procedure",con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = bank.name;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Aha! That's where I was going wroong, not adding the EndUser endUser when I first tried to pass the objects through the method! Ugh silly mistake, also yes the stored procedure isn't above as I didn't feel it was relevant, it is written and ready to be used. Once again, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of design principles actually shy away from doing CRUD operations in the objects nowadays, preferring to accept the object as an argument to a data service layer. Your code should actually be *larger*, not smaller. An example service would be:

```
public Bank(string bn, string scode)
    {
        name = bn;
        sortcode = scode;
    }
    public string name { get; set; } // textbox6
    public string sortcode { get; set; } // textbox5
}
class BankDataService
{
    public void SaveNewBankToDatabase(Bank bank) {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDatabase"].ConnectionString))
        {
            string sqlQuery = (@"INSERT INTO [Bank] (BankName, SortCode)
                            VALUES (@BankName, @SortCode)");
            connection.Open();

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("BankName", bank.name);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("SortCode", bank.sortcode);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
    public void UpdateBankToDatabase(Bank bank) {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDatabase"].ConnectionString))
        {
            string sqlQuery = (@"UPDATE [Bank]
                               SET SortCode=@SortCode
                               WHERE @BankName=@BankName");
            connection.Open();

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("BankName", bank.name);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("SortCode", bank.sortcode);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
    public void SelectBankFromDatabase(string bankName) {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDatabase"].ConnectionString))
        {
            string sqlQuery = (@"SELECT BankName, SortCode FROM [Bank] WHERE BankName=@BankName");
            connection.Open();

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("BankName", bank.name);
                using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
                     if(reader.Read()){
                          return new Bank { BankName=reader["BankName"].ToString(), SortCode=reader["SortCode"].ToString(); }
                     }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry misread completely, the problem would still persist though, I would need the above across all classes, rather than using the class objects in one storedproc class.

Comment: Sorry my naming is unclear. The bank data service just saves your bank detail to the database. You can create an "Update" and "Select" operation in your data service tier in order to interact with the database and retrieve old banks and stuff, but without more code from your program I can't write much code to give you a concrete example.

Comment: Apologies completely overwrote my other comment as I misread the naming of the initial example.

Comment: I've been making edits to up the code. I also added a select and update (which I just assumed from the bank model). That's just an example set of CRU operations in a dataservice layer. You won't be able to generalize your database layer like you want unless you use Entity Framework, which abstracts the concept of the database layer away from the code used to write to the database.

Comment: Thanks for your help upvoted as very useful, will add that data layer to my code, but Landeyoo got what I was trying to say first, badly worded q but couldn't think of another way to get across what I meant.